# DOM Parser Using Flex and Bison

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am working on a project to create a DOM parser. At the initial stage I am simply trying to figure out how many tags are there in the given file. Let's say I have an XML file whose content is somewhat like this : `<abc>`this is test file`</abc>`
, for this I only want to parse the two tags `<abc>` and `</abc>`. For this happen I am using Flex and Bison to write a grammar so that whenever this grammar occurs I execute my code. This is my Bison code :

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    int yylex();
    int yyparse();
    FILE *yyin;
    int yylineno;
    void yyerror(const char*);
%}

%token START_TAG END_TAG 

%%
tag:
    sTag
    | eTag
    ;
sTag:
    START_TAG {printf("start tag encountered");}
    ;
eTag:
    END_TAG
    ;
%%
int main(){
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("G:\\MCA-2\\project\\09-03-2013\\demo.txt","r");
    if(!myFile){
        printf("error opening file");
    }
    yyin = myFile;
    do{
        yyparse();
    } while(!feof(yyin));
    fclose(myFile);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my Flex code :

```
%{
    #include "xml.tab.h"
    #define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
%}

%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
alpha [a-zA-Z]
digit [0-9]
%%
[ \t] {}
[ \n] {}
{alpha}({alpha}|{digit})* return START_TAG;
%%
```

When I am trying to compile this I am getting an error like this :

lex.yy.c : 529:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant.

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake I am making?

Comment: How are you compiling "this" (I think you mean `lex.yy.c`) The declaration `extern "C"...` is only valid in C++, not in C, and normally `file.c` would be compiled as C.

Comment: I am compiling in following manner : gcc lex.yy.c xml.tab.c -o xml.exe. I removed extern "C" just to try variation but then to the error didnt go.

Comment: So you're compiling it as a C program. In that case, get rid of the `#define YY_DECL` line altogether, since the default declaration will be fine. Don't forget to run `flex` every time you change your flex file, to regenerate `lex.yy.c`.

Comment: Thank you rici for solving my problem. I got my solution. I removed #define YY_DECL and the problem got solved. Can you explain what was the problem actually?

Comment: See the second sentence of my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

(Question answered in the comments; see: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@rici Provided the answer. As flex is generating C code for the gcc compiler *get rid of the `#define YY_DECL` line altogether, since the default declaration will be fine. Don't forget to run flex every time you change your flex file, to regenerate lex.yy.c. The declaration `extern "C"...` is only valid in C++, not in C, and normally `file.c` would be compiled as C.*